# Second EditText Skipped

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#2A2E43"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/white"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="272dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="4dp" />
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/deviceNameAndAddressText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="not connected"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
    android:src="@drawable/one" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/initial"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="initial"
    android:textColor="#2A2E43"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/one"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/denaturaion"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:text="Denaturation"
    android:textColor="#2A2E43"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/one"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/initial" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/temp1"
    android:layout_width="57dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:hint="\u2103"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/denaturaion"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/deviceNameAndAddressText"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/mm_1"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/mm_1"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="mm"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/temp1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/colon"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/colon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text=":"
    android:textColor="#2A2E43"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/mm_1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/ss_1"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ss_1"
    android:layout_width="53dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:hint="ss"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/colon"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
    /></androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my layout file. I am using constraint layout.When I am clicking next in the keypad the second edittext is skipped after first Edittext and focus the third eedittext. Please help me to sortout the issue.How to work on this issue, searched in google for solution no solutions

Answer (score 1):

You can use these methods in your XML file for change focus according.

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/.."  
android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/.."    
android:nextFocusRight="@+id/.."    
android:nextFocusUp="@+id/.."
```

Comment: To add to this answer, you can read more about the purposed solution at https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/navigation#Direction